# iOS: UIView losing tap recognition with UITabGestureRecognizer enabled

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitextfield, uikit

I am using an imported button object, Floaty (https://github.com/kciter/Floaty) which is a subclass of the UIView class. In one of the view controllers where I am using this button (which includes a Text Field), the button fails to be selected when tapped if I include the following line to close the keyboard when tapped away from...

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard (_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

The idea for how to close the keyboard came from this SO query: [iOS - Dismiss keyboard when touching outside of UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/ios-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-uitextfield)

I thought part of the issue could be that the Floaty button needs to be in the front, so I added the following line of code, found from this SO query: [Losing tap recognition after adding a UIScrollView under a UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887017/losing-tap-recognition-after-adding-a-uiscrollview-under-a-uibutton)

```
floaty.bringSubviewToFront(self.view)
```

I added this line to the end of my ViewDidLoad() function in the view where it is used.

(Important maybe to note is that all of the aforementioned code is in the ViewDidLoad function for my view controller)

Is there another way to handle closing a keyboard when tapping away from a text field? Or is there something else that I should do to the Floaty (UIView) object to handle tap / touch events?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use Hit Testing. With hit testing, you can assign a view that handles touch. This great article explains how to apply hit testing http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/